# How to limit CPU usage of a process

Tags: c#

I want to create a program which can limit cpu usage of a process even when the computer is idle.

I have made a program that set priority of process, but if the computer is idle, the cpu usage can reach 95%. The process contains "element" is the process that I want to limit

```cs
private static readonly string[] RestrictedProcess = new[] { "element" }; 
static void ProcessChecker(object o)
{
    List<Process> resProc = new List<Process>();
    foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        string s = p.ProcessName;
        foreach(string rp in RestrictedProcess)
        {
            s = s.ToLower();
            if (s.Contains(rp))
                resProc.Add(p);
        }
    }

    foreach(Process p in resProc)
    {
        p.PriorityBoostEnabled = false;
        p.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;
        p.MaxWorkingSet = new IntPtr(20000000);
    }

    SetPowerConfig(resProc.Count > 0 ? PowerOption.GreenComputing : PowerOption.Balanced);
}
```

Comment: I think that your question is operating system specific and should be tagged as such. I believe your program don't compile with `mono` on Linux. So your question is more operating system specific than language specific.

Comment: If the computer is not in use (ie idle), why is it a problem that a process uses 95% of the CPU?

Comment: If the choice is between doing *nothing*, and achieving useful work, why would the OS choose to do nothing? The way to get a process to use less CPU is to have a higher priority process doing something.

Comment: If CPU usage is high, it consumes more energy and my electricity bill on my house can increases.. I don't want that.. To reduce energy consumtion, I wan't to slow down the CPU..

Comment: Then tell the OS that you want to save power, and let it manage that, i.e. visit the power options control panel.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to change _priority_ of CPU processes, but _throttle_ the CPU. In which case, as Damien said use the power options to reduce the max usage down from 100%. In Win 7, it can be found here: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the program you want to limit is not yours, there are several options:

- **set the process priority as `Idle` and do not limit the CPU usage** as the CPU should be used as much as possible in any case. It's OK to have your CPU running 100% all the time if there is something useful to do. If the priority is `idle`, then the CPU usage of this particular process will be reduced if another program requires CPU.
- if your system is multi-core or multi-cpu, then **you might want to set the [processor affinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity.aspx)**. This will tell your program to use only the processor(s) you want him to use. For example, if your program is multithreaded and able to consume 100% of your two CPUs, then set his affinity to only use one CPU. His usage will then be 50% only.
- Worst option but **actually used by 90% of the "CPU limiter programs"** you'll find on the web: measure the CPU usage of a process and Suspend and Resume it regularly until it's CPU usage goes to the value you want.

To suspend/resume a process that is not yours, you'll have to use P/Invoke (and this requires to have access to the process, so if you are Windows Vista or above, take care of UAC for admin rights):

```
/// <summary>
/// The process-specific access rights.
/// </summary>
[Flags]
public enum ProcessAccess : uint
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required to terminate a process using TerminateProcess.
    /// </summary>
    Terminate = 0x1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to create a thread.
    /// </summary>
    CreateThread = 0x2,

    /// <summary>
    /// Undocumented.
    /// </summary>
    SetSessionId = 0x4,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to perform an operation on the address space of a process (see VirtualProtectEx and WriteProcessMemory).
    /// </summary>
    VmOperation = 0x8,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to read memory in a process using ReadProcessMemory.
    /// </summary>
    VmRead = 0x10,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to write to memory in a process using WriteProcessMemory.
    /// </summary>
    VmWrite = 0x20,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to duplicate a handle using DuplicateHandle.
    /// </summary>
    DupHandle = 0x40,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to create a process.
    /// </summary>
    CreateProcess = 0x80,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to set memory limits using SetProcessWorkingSetSize.
    /// </summary>
    SetQuota = 0x100,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to set certain information about a process, such as its priority class (see SetPriorityClass).
    /// </summary>
    SetInformation = 0x200,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to retrieve certain information about a process, such as its token, exit code, and priority class (see OpenProcessToken, GetExitCodeProcess, GetPriorityClass, and IsProcessInJob).
    /// </summary>
    QueryInformation = 0x400,

    /// <summary>
    /// Undocumented.
    /// </summary>
    SetPort = 0x800,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to suspend or resume a process.
    /// </summary>
    SuspendResume = 0x800,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to retrieve certain information about a process (see QueryFullProcessImageName). A handle that has the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access right is automatically granted PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION.
    /// </summary>
    QueryLimitedInformation = 0x1000,

    /// <summary>
    /// Required to wait for the process to terminate using the wait functions.
    /// </summary>
    Synchronize = 0x100000
}

[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
internal static extern uint NtResumeProcess([In] IntPtr processHandle);

[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
internal static extern uint NtSuspendProcess([In] IntPtr processHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
    ProcessAccess desiredAccess,
    bool inheritHandle,
    int processId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool CloseHandle([In] IntPtr handle);

public static void SuspendProcess(int processId)
{
    IntPtr hProc = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        // Gets the handle to the Process
        hProc = OpenProcess(ProcessAccess.SuspendResume, false, processId);

        if (hProc != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            NtSuspendProcess(hProc);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Don't forget to close handle you created.
        if (hProc != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(hProc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is why I love this site.  I always learn so many interesting things.  +1 for some awesome information!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact command for C#, but it would be a command that gives control back to the operating system.  I think in C++ it might be a delay or sleep that will do that.  So the equivalent call in C# that will delay the code and give cycles back to the OS.

Comment: [`Thread.Sleep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx) is what you are probably referring to.

Comment: The process that I want to limit is not created by me.. It's just a game.

Comment: If you want to slow down a game you need to find out if the speed is cpu or clock bound. If it is clock bound it will be useless to limit cpu usage.